# ClassCastException for MappingFactory to ToMany while porting to grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-orm, datastore, hibernate-4.x, grails-3.1

When trying to run command `grails run-app --stacktrace`, grails is throwing this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.MappingFactory$10 cannot be cast to org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.types.ToMany
```

I commented `static hasMany` from all the domain classes but error still persisted, until I replaced it with **hibernate3** in my `build.gradle`

How can I solve this using **hibernate4**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, actually it had to do with `embedded grails domain property`.

Comment: What is the resolution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As @deepen mention, this error is related with the mapping setup of the embedded domain classes. In my case, I was using multiples databases (mongodb gorm 6.0.12 + jtds (sql server)), and some of the documents had embedded properties (defined in the same class).

```
DomainA.groovy
class DomainA
    static hasMany = [domainBs: DomainB]
    static embedded = ['domainBs']
    static mapWith = "mongo"

class DomainB
    // if embedded: what's the point of this? 
    static belongsTo = [domainB: DomainA]
    // if i'll use it as embedded, doesn't add nothing
    static mapWith = "mongo"
```

In short, if I comment `belongsTo` and `mapWith` in the definition of the embedded class, the issue was solved. If not, *must* remember to `mapWith` embedded class with same datasource as container class.